# ERROR 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'replace' PYTHON

Tags: python

I have an error in my coding

```
import pandas as pd

#slang word
path_dataslang = open("kamus kata baku 1.csv")
dataslang = pd.read_csv(path_dataslang, encoding='utf-8', header=None, sep=";")

def replaceSlang(word):
  if word in list(dataslang[0]):
    indexslang = list(dataslang[0]).index(word)
    return dataslang[1][indexslang]
  else:
    return word

data_formal = []
for data in data_tokens:
  data_clean = [replaceSlang(word) for word in data]
  data_formal.append(data_clean)
len_data_formal = len(data_formal)
print(data_formal)
len_data_formal
```

---

```
UnicodeDecodeError                        
Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-106-e464e8c47fd4> in <module>
      3 #slang word
      4 path_dataslang = open("kamus kata baku 1.csv")
----> 5 dataslang = pd.read_csv(path_dataslang, encoding='utf-8', header=None, sep=";")
      6 
      7 def replaceSlang(word):

9 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.raise_parser_error()

UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xb2 in position 11: invalid start byte
```

Comment: so your file is not utf8-encoded.